# swift send array to web service parameters

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to send array object to web service, but when I try to  add array to parameters it gives error. I tried many things but nothing found usefully.

I want to add `("assignees" : newList)` in parameter and than send it to web service

Here is my code

```
    var newList = [Assignee]()
    var assignee = Assignee()
    for u in task.NewWorkList! {
        assignee =  Assignee()
        assignee.assignedEmail = u.Email
        assignee.assignedName = u.Name
        assignee.assignedSurname = u.Surname
        assignee.assignedType = "PERSONEL"
        assignee.assignedTo = String(u.Id!)
        newList.append(assignee)
    }

// in this part newList is an array of assignees.

    var assigneeListString = ""
   let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(newList)
        assigneeListString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("assigneeListString:",assigneeListString) 
    } catch {
        print("error:::")
    }
```

```
    var parameters = [
            "taskType" :
                [
                    "code" : "OTHER"
                ],
            "complateButtons": "COMPLATE",
           "assignees" :  [JSON(assigneeListString)], // does not work
           // "assignees" :  [JSON(newList)], // does not work
           // "assignees" :  JSON(newList), // does not work
           // "assignees" :  newList, // does not work
          // "assignees" :  assigneeListString, // does not work
            "repeatTimeType":"NEVER"
            ] as [String : Any]

       print("parameters:",parameters)
        DAL.Service.MakeRequest(url: Constants.Service.Url.newTask,
                                parameters : parameters,
                                httpMethod : ServiceMethods.post.rawValue,
                                resultFunc: serviceResultFunc)
```

when I print parameters assignee section adds extra semi colon,

```
[[{"assignedTo":"63659","assignedSurname":"DAVID","assignedType":"PERSONEL","assignedName":"JOE","assignedEmail":"joe@abc.com"},{"assignedTo":"21026","assignedSurname":"GEORGE","assignedType":"PERSONEL","assignedName":"MICHAEL","assignedEmail":"michael@abc.com"}]],
```

when I manually add assignees to patameters , its ok.

```
[["assignedTo":"63659","assignedSurname":"DAVID","assignedType":"PERSONEL","assignedName":"JOE","assignedEmail":"joe@abc.com"},{"assignedTo":"21026","assignedSurname":"GEORGE","assignedType":"PERSONEL","assignedName":"MICHAEL","assignedEmail":"michael@abc.com"]],
```

Comment: Maybe: `"assignees" = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with below code:

```
          var assigneesList = [[String:Any]]()
             for a in task.YeniGorevAtamaList! {
                  assigneesList.append(
                      ["assignedTo":(a.Id) ?? "0",
                       "assignedSurname":a.Surname ?? "",
                       "assignedType":a.assignedType ?? "PERSONEL",
                       "assignedName":a.Name ?? "",
                       "assignedEmail":a.Email as Any
                      ]
                      );
            }

let parameters = [
                "taskType" :
                    [
                        "code" : "DIGER"
                    ],  
                 "assignees" : assigneesList ,
                "taskUrls" :
                    [
                    ]
                ] as [String : Any]
```